# POP connector Exchange Server 2010

Tags: email, exchange-2010, encrypting-file-system

An old server with Exchange 2003 is being replaced with a new 2008 R2 server (x64) running Exchange 2010.

On that 2003 machine we had a tool called EFS (Email Forwarding System) but the tool is old and doesn't have Exchange 2010 listed as a supported environment. 
The website itself has also a warning for Exchange 2010:

> (* NOTE: Some users have reported issues with blank HTML formatted emails sent to Exchange 2010. Earlier versions of Exchange are unaffected. The fault is not actually EFS, but a 3rd party mail control that we use. We are trying to track down the source code from that vendor so that the problem can be fixed. We do not have a time frame that this will be fixed by yet. We apologise for any inconvenience caused)

Does this POP connector functionality come out of the box with Exchange Server 2010 or do you still need such tool? 
If so: how do you configure it or what (free?) tool would you recommend that has the same or more options like EFS.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this to retrieve emails from a pop server? Exchange does not have this ability built-in.

There are lots of competitors for this product, but we do not recommend commercial products on this site.

A better idea would be to rethink mail delivery. If you need a third party to hold your email for you because your internet connection is unreliable, then look for an mx host instead of a mailbox host.